# HEALTHCHECK starting container process caused invalid environment USERNAME

Tags: docker, curl, dockerfile, health-monitoring

After adding to my docker file the health check:

```
HEALTHCHECK --interval=2m --timeout=30s --retries=5 CMD curl -r http://localhost:1234/healthstatus || exit 1
```

I’m getting unhealthy alert under the status in docker ps (the container is up):
Up About an hour (unhealthy)

```
CONTAINER ID        IMAGE                                                                      COMMAND                  CREATED             STATUS                         PORTS                                          NAMES
jdhfjksdhfk        my_docker_register/my_service                   "/usr/src/app/entr..."   About an hour ago   Up About an hour (unhealthy)   0.0.0.0:1234->1234/tcp, 0.0.0.0:80->1234/tcp   my_service
```

after checking the health log I can see the output:

```
docker inspect --format=’{{json .State}}’ my_service | jq .
```

> { “Health”: { “Log”: [ { “Output”: “rpc error: code = 2 desc = oci
>   runtime error: exec failed: container_linux.go:247: starting container
>   process caused “invalid environment ‘USERNAME’”\n”, “ExitCode”: -1,
>   “End”: “2017-12-10T10:28:42.274606327Z”, “Start”:
>   “2017-12-10T10:28:42.241716647Z” }, { “Output”: “rpc error: code = 2
>   desc = oci runtime error: exec failed: container_linux.go:247:
>   starting container process caused “invalid environment ‘USERNAME’”\n”,
>   “ExitCode”: -1, “End”: “2017-12-10T10:30:42.313609006Z”, “Start”:
>   “2017-12-10T10:30:42.274847833Z” }, { “Output”: “rpc error: code = 2
>   desc = oci runtime error: exec failed: container_linux.go:247:
>   starting container process caused “invalid environment ‘USERNAME’”\n”,
>   “ExitCode”: -1, “End”: “2017-12-10T10:32:42.347550172Z”, “Start”:
>   “2017-12-10T10:32:42.313834355Z” }, { “Output”: “rpc error: code = 2
>   desc = oci runtime error: exec failed: container_linux.go:247:
>   starting container process caused “invalid environment ‘USERNAME’”\n”,
>   “ExitCode”: -1, “End”: “2017-12-10T10:34:42.380622433Z”, “Start”:
>   “2017-12-10T10:34:42.347742726Z” } ], “FailingStreak”: 4, “Status”:
>   “starting” },

when i’m doing docker exec with the same command it works fine:

```
docker exec -it my_service curl -r http://localhost:1234/healthstatus || exit 1
```

output: ok

any idea how to fix this?

Answer (score 0):

So my issue was actually due to environment variable '**USERNAME**' that was configured in my docker compose file but with value of **null**

```
version: "2"
services:
  my-service:
    image: registry/ramp-webapp
    restart: always
    environment:
      NODE_ENV: {{node_env}}
      USERNAME:
      CONSUL_AGENT_HOST: {{ ansible_eth0.ipv4.address }}
    ports:
      - "80:80"
    container_name: my-service
    volumes:
      - /var/log/my-service:/var/log/my-service
```

I really don't know why environment variable that is set to null is causing this issue.

my solution was to **remove** the USERNAME environment variable from the docker compose

Comment: do you mean fill up an issue in docker github project?

Comment: Yes github.com/moby/moby.